# How do I get github's live-server to reload my pages automatically?

Tags: node.js, server

newbie here. Initially I had trouble installing live server as seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q78u9lBXvj0. Took me a while to search and figure out the problem.

I had to install node.js, followed by using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Then I had trouble with the `npm install -g`, kept getting these errors. Turns out I had to use 'sudo' in front. So that worked and it installed.

Now, whenever I get into the terminal, get into my folder and type `live-server`, a new `http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/` page will appear. I seem to be able to see what is the current progress, but it won't auto refresh whenever I make any changes. I'm not sure if it's because I've installed it incorrectly or if it's because of a setting.

One thing I noticed is that in the video, whenever he types `live-server` he also gets the two lines below of `'send deprecated send.root...'` which I don't get.

I simply get the first line of 'serving...' followed by path directory and then 'at http:// 127.0.0.1:8080' whereas his is 'at http: //localhost:8080'

I'm assuming it might be a setting issue, but I can't figure out what the problem is. So how do I get github's live-server to reload my pages automatically?

Comment: One comment: Just because the code for this project is hosted on Github, doesn't mean that Github itself is affiliated with it. This is just another open source project, which besides the hosting of the repository has nothing to do with Github. Therefore i remove the tags for git and github.

Comment: Got a look in your network tab on the f12-developer tools?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you use a browser which doesn't support WebSockets. As the documentation states:

> If there are errors, deal with them. You will need a browser that supports WebSockets.

Comment: Hi Dunni, I'm using Chrome and I've already tested for WebSockets, its supported.